# How to convert data to excel with bash

Tags: excel, bash, shell, awk

I have the file called "result" in my filesystem. It looks like:

```
Name of file|NoSQL|C++|Anglais|Rigueur|ITIL|Django|jQuery|Python|PHP|HTML|CodeIgniter|ERP|C#|XML|Ajax|JavaScript|UML|SQL|C|Doxygen|VBA|SharePoint|MySQL|MVC|iOS|Android|WinRT
00011-Stage Développeur Web.txt|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|1|0|0|0
00012-Stage_Alyotech.txt|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|0|0|0|0|0|1|3|2
00013-Stage_Orange_Business_Services_Virtualisation.txt|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
00738-STAGE BE3.txt|4|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

I want to convert this data to excel document in a separate columns, but I don't know how to perform it.

I have read about `awk` but I can't understand how to implement it in my situation.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sed -i 's/|/,/'` would be a start. Of course you could also just tell Excel what your column separator is directly when you open the file.

Comment: Literally just specify the separator in excel, no more work needed. No need for sed at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know, that's posible to choose separator directly in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You could use join or awk, and I think that there are other solutions.

join

If you want join to files with same column, look these posts: Bash join command and join in bash like in SAS

awk

You could write a csv, but you could rename into xls and then with excel, gnumeric, or other programs, it is recognized like xls.

ls -R -ltr / | head -50 | awk '{if ($5 >0) print $5,$9}' OFS="," > sample.xls

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I've already figure out this issue. Just opened my text file in Excel and choose separator.